# How to pass data to Link button onclick event

Tags: c#, html

/*help me i am stuck here  on how to pass <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Site_No") %> as parm to link button when clicked  */

```
                <ItemTemplate >

                        <!-- small box -->
                    <div class='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Status") %>'>
                        <div class="inner">

                            <h3><asp:Label ID="lblSiteNo" runat="server"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Site_No") %><sup style="font-size: 20px"></sup></asp:Label></h3>

                            <p><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Site_Size") %></p>
                        </div>



                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1"  CssClass="small-box-footer" OnClick="" runat="server">More info</asp:LinkButton>
                    </div>


                </ItemTemplate>



            </asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `OnClick` event, use the `CommandName` and `CommandArgument` properties.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1"  CssClass="small-box-footer" CommandName="MoreInfo_Command" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PARAM_NAME") %>'  runat="server">More info</asp:LinkButton>
```

In your code behind:

```
      void MoreInfo_Command(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
      {
         string parameter = e.CommandArgument;
      }
```

Comment: <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2"  CssClass="small-box-footer" OnClick="ENameLinkBtn_Click" CausesValidation="false" CommandArgument=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Site_No") %>  runat="server">More info</asp:LinkButton>

Comment: You should remove the onclick and put this code inside the item template section